# Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11001ms." when user browser.getCurrentUrl()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, angularjs-resource

I am testing login and logout functionality, below is my test cases

```
it('should redirect to login page on click of logout',function(){
    signInPage.email.sendKeys('zahid.afaque@meltwater.com');
    signInPage.password.sendKeys(1234);
    signInPage.loginButton.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/collections/);
    signInPage.profileImage.click();
    signInPage.logout.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/login/);
});
```

When i run above test its failing and below is the error message

```
Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11001ms. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
```

i tried using `browser.waitForAngular();` but it does not help. When i removed expect `"expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/login/);"` then it is getting passed. Anyone have come across with same problem, any help is appricated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you are facing the same issue as I did. For me the app was constantly sending requests and thus was never finished.

Adding the following line after the "click()" fixed it for me:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

[Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548366/angularjs-e2e-tests-hang-when-changing-between-two-separate-angular-apps)

Answer (score 0):

ptor.sleep(1000) instead of wait for angular not ideal but works for me

Comment: @aksu yes it does, my answer will work if its substituted for the browser.waitForAngular it will work

Comment: Hey Sirk, i tried that as well but it does not work.